# Hyper-V Switch Manager не загружается (loading...)

Tags: hyper-v

Есть Windows 10 с установленной Hyper-V. Hyper-V длительное время более-менее успешно работал, но недавно после применения патча MicrosoftEasyFix20159.mini перестал запускаться Hyper-V Switch Manager и я не могу настроить сеть.

Кто сталкивался? Как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: >перестал запускаться Hyper-V Switch Manager и я не могу настроить сеть.
>Кто сталкивался? Как исправить?